# How send 2 params in action by link_to, if 1 params exist on page and I can get this value by JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm beginner in ror. I have page with datatable. When I choose tr in datatable and push button I want send in action 1 values(I can get this by JS) from tr, and 1 values from code( send by link_to). I don't know why do this. How combine result JS and link_to, and catch this in action. I'm confused...

```
$.get('mycontroller/create', {user_id: "current_user.id", h_id: $(this).data("h-id")});
```

Don't find `current_user.id`

```
<%= link_to "Add to h-list", my_controller_create_path(current_user.id), method: :post , :class => "btn btn-default">
```

don't sending `h_id`

```
def create
    @h = h.new(????)
    @h.save
    end
```

I want get value in action and write it in database. Please help me

Comment: ror?! please read how to ask question in stackoverflow in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorry,  got nervous

Comment: which value need to send to the create action??

Comment: change `my_controller_create_path(current_user.id)` to `my_controller_create_path(:id => current_user.id)`

Comment: current_user.id (from code) and h_id(from web-page)

Comment: in order to do this i think making a ajax call by clicking the button is a better solution.you get the h_id from page to js and pass to the ajax method from there you will get the current_user too.

Comment: please, give some example ajax call. I did ajax call single by JS, but i don't represent how do this in combination with link_to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**your_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @h = h.new(your_params)
    @h.h_id_attribute = params[:h-id]
    @h.save
 end
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#someId").attr('href', function(_, href){
    return href+'?h-id=your_value'
});
```

**in your view**

```
<%= link_to 'mylink', my_controller_create_path(current_user.id), class: 'someClass', id: 'someId'  %>
```

Can you try that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, do you want 1 of your link_to parameters to be retrieved via your js? Why not play with the "href" attribute of the link generated by your link_to?

I would have done so:

Ruby (ERB)

```
<%= link_to 'mylink', your_path, class: 'someClass', id: 'someId'  %>
```

JS (jQuery)

```
   $("#someId").attr('href', function(_, href){
        return href+'?param=value'
    });
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: I don' understant, who will call action, erb or js. Or you say do it only js(jquery)?

Comment: The link_to will target your controller action, then about the parameters, I would have done that only in JS since there is one that is dynamic from what you say, and then in your controller, you can get the value via params[:my_param]. 

Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks you, for answer, but I can get value h_id via js, right? I have values current_user.id from devise, witch must send to controller too. My target send two parametr in contoller and save it in database. I don't understand how send user_id and h_id together.

Comment: Yes, but you have to "append" this params h_id to the generated link_to link as i show you in my answer.